# What are the bundles.js files that appear on the Github code archive for the book "HTML5 Games: Novice to Ninja"?

Tags: javascript, html, github

I recently purchased *HTML5 Games: Novice to Ninja* by Earle Casteldine. In the third chapter of the book, it walks you through making a basic game library that is used for the rest of the book. I have the exact same code as presented in the book, but I was getting a console error reading `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` so I went to the [GitHub code archive](https://github.com/spbooks/html5games1). In each project, I found a file named `bundles.js` that was never mentioned in the book. Furthermore, instead of the `main.js` file being the source of the script, the `bundles.js` files were.

When I copied the `bundles.js` file from the GitHub project html5games1/ch03/10-library-entity/ the program ran and worked fine. What are the bundle files and why doesn't the program work without them?

If this question made no sense, I'm sorry. This is my first time posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundle.js is a common name a javascript packager (like webpack or browserify) will use to create a single file with all of an app's javascript in it, so it can be loaded by the browser with a single `<script>` tag.

It looks like they are using browserify.  You can see how they call it in some of the package.json files:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "budo src/main.js:bundle.js --live -- -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ]",
    "build": "browserify src/main.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ]"
  },
```

They're also using babel, which converts modern JS to legacy JS to make it work on more browsers.

Comment: so considering that I am relatively new to programming with javascript, if I were to use multiple `<script>` tags would I not need to have a bundle.js?

Comment: bundling is mainly for the purpose of deploying your app on the Internet.  When learning, I'd recommend you keep it simple and just have your scripts either in script tags or use script tags to point to the javascript files directly.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle.js` is usually generated by Webpack. You may be using cutting edge JavaScript which gets compiled with Babel using Webpack. Or you may be using `live reloading` with Webpack server.